# ajax and node.js server not working together

Tags: node.js

i have a node.js server that loads an html page and listens. the page is displayed by the browser and when i click a button the page sends an ajax message to the server ...

```
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log("post2 url="+url);
  xhr.open("GET", url); 
  xhr.onload = function () {
    let rsp=this.responseText;
    console.log("onload rsp:"+rsp);
    //hndlr(rsp);
  }
  xhr.send();
```

the server gets the message and i see it via console.log at the server. i then reply `rsp.write(string)` but the browser receives a page load rather than the string and i see at the browser via console.log

> > XML Parsing Error: syntax error
> > Location: http://localhost:12137/?fetch|products|row0|ukey|dscr|cost|onhnd|value|splyr|uom|mnstck|restck
> > Line Number 1, Column 1: localhost:12137:1:1
> >
> > > 

what am i doing wrong?